# Do companies shop for 0-days on black markets to fix them?

Tags: zero-day, vulnerability-markets

Is it known for software development companies to shop for 0-day vulnerabilities on black markets in order to burn them?

Microeconomics tell me "no", as [some sources claim](https://www.cyberscoop.com/zero-day-vulns-are-rarer-and-more-expensive-than-ever/) that 0-days are short in supply, thus really expensive these days due to combined efforts of security companies and such, and as we know from "Fight Club", "If X [cost of failure] is less than the cost of a recall, we don't do one." :)

But I would imagine that there could be somebody who does this for high-profile enterprise customers, or at least for a publicity stunt, and I just didn't happen to find out about it.

If there is such a company, I want to know their story.
If there seems to be none, I'd be happy to state the reasons.

Comment: Many companies now have a reward program (Bug Bounty Program) where flaws can be responsibly disclosed in return of monetary compensation. You are not talking about these, are you?

Comment: @Marcel No, I am speaking specifically of black markets. I am pretty sure there could be some Chaotic Evil black-hat hackers, who sell 0-days on black markets specifically to disrupt the companies/society/etc

Comment: See also here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Market_for_zero-day_exploits

Comment: Is it not what Zerodium does? On behalf of their high-profile clients (governments, F250) ?

Comment: @FlorianBidabe Quick Google search shows that with a little more details, you could make that a good answer

Comment: @vadkou well zerodium isn't a software company and isn't buying exploits on the black market. Hence why I made it a comment. It doesn't quite answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I know of a few, but companies will not be public in their efforts to search for and purchase 0-days because: 1) if publicly known, it would increase the price, and 2) it creates a greater demand, which means greater incentive for attackers to hunt for 0-days, which increases the risks for the company.

That's why they use Bug Bounty programs instead. It flips the market so that the company benefits more directly without increasing the risks.